# Table with navigable values in Salesforce Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, datatable

I am new to Salesforce Lightning and I would like to make a table that has values that I could click on, and open the object details in another tab.

In salesforce Classic, I did this way:

```
<apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Address__c.Fields.ConectionObject__c.Label}"> 
    <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Connection_Object__c.View, item.ConectionObject__c)}">{!item.ConectionObject__r.Name}</apex:outputLink>
</apex:column>
```

And at the moment, my code is the next one:

```
<td>
    <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!dir.ConectionObject__c}">{!dir.ConectionObject__r.Name}
    </div>
</td>
```

But I don't know how to make it navigable (I guess that is using a kind of link)
I have checked to **ui:outputURL** or to **ui:inputURL** but I don't know how they work.

Cheers

Comment: Can you try  `<a href="{!'/one/one.app?#/sObject/'+ dir.ConectionObject__c + '/view'}" target="_blank">{!dir.ConectionObject__r.Name}</a>`

Comment: Then you can accept this answer and close this question.

Comment: I would not hardcode /one/one.app in the link as url format will change in Summer '18: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000269064&language=en_US&type=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try basic anchor tag to achieve this.

```
<a href="{!'/one/one.app?#/sObject/'+ dir.ConectionObject__c + '/view'}" target="_blank">{!dir.ConectionObject__r.Name}</a>
```